# SQL Server 2017 on Linux/Kubernetes -- Set up TLS Security

Tags: sql-server, ssl-certificate, x509certificate

Trying to configure TLS on my MSSQL connections following this article:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-encrypted-connections?view=sql-server-2017

The server-side configuration seems pretty straight-forward with minor differences in the container environment (e.g. systemctl doesn't exist so I kill/respawn pod):

```
systemctl stop mssql-server 
cat /var/opt/mssql/mssql.conf 
/opt/mssql/bin/mssql-conf set network.tlscert /var/opt/mssql/ssl/mssql.pem 
/opt/mssql/bin/mssql-conf set network.tlskey /var/opt/mssql/ssl/mssqlprivkey.key
/opt/mssql/bin/mssql-conf set network.tlsprotocols 1.2 
/opt/mssql/bin/mssql-conf set network.forceencryption 0 
systemctl start mssql-server
```

So I took my PFX from my Windows CA and extracted the key and the client cert to key and pem files, added them to the location for persistent storage (/var/opt), ran the commands (seen above) and sql came back up.

I installed mssql-tools on a different machine and configured it in the trust-anchors to trust my CA.

However, when trying to test the connection (`sqlcmd -N -S tcp:1.1.1.1,1433 -U user -P password`), I get the error:   `SSL Provider: [error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed:subject name does not match host name]`

When I change the connection string to the DNS name, **it works** (`sqlcmd -N -S tcp:mssql.mydomain.com,1433 -U user -P password`) -- even though the IP address is listed as a subject alternative name on the cert.

Why are secure connections not working using the IP?  What am I missing?

Comment: How IP address is defined in SAN extension? As IP Address or DNS name type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Different TLS client tools differently handle IP Address Subject Alternative Name type. Most Microsoft tools ignore `iPAddress` name type completely and require IP addresses to be listed as `dNSName` name type. Try to add IP Address to SAN extension as `dNSName` name type, it should work.